# Composite forms using django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

## -------------Models

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()


class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    contact = models.ForeignKey('Contact')


class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    contact = models.ForeignKey('Contact')
```

## -------------Model Serializers

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact


class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client


class VendorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
```

The 'Client Form' should have the following fields:
All fields of Client Model &
All fields of Contact Model

Is this possible using a single 'ClientSerializer'?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by `Client Form` you are talking about a serializer for an API endpoint (and I understand your question correctly):

Since the `Client` and `Vendor` are linked to `Contact`, you can add these as sub-structures.

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    clients = ClientSerializer(many=True)
    vendors = VendorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

See the [documentation on nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#nested-relationships).